# Asp.net build output directory giving parse error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am getting below error in the browser when I am setting my build output folder to `../bin/debug` or `../bin/release`. But if I set it to `../bin` it is working fine.  Also setting it to `../bin/debug` is creating all output files in the debug directory but not reading the libraries from the directory it seems.

Please help if anyone have any workaround for this issue.

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type <>

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: How many projects do you have? And why are you changing the output path?

Comment: Since I am using different configurations for different environments like debug,release,test,acceptance etc. there are different output path for different environments for easy deployment

Comment: The output path should be automatic by the `configuration` variable

Comment: Right-click project->Properties->Build event and type the command below in Post build event command line:               
copy $(ProjectDir)$(OutPutPath) $(ProjectDir)bin /y

Comment: This issue results from the option can't find sources.Copy the output files to temp bin folder can resolve it. Please check if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you use ‘View in browser’ option, by default it will search source files from bin folder as it’s original output folder.

And since you’ve changed the output path like bin\Debug. When using this option, the source files which should be in bin folder but now at bin\Debug folder can’t be reached. That’s the cause of this issue.

To resolve it we could add a command**: `copy $(ProjectDir)$(OutPutPath) $(ProjectDir)bin /y` into post-build event. It works to copy the new output files to bin folder after every successful build no matter what the output path it is.

Please check if it works. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Exactly this is what I want. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Which option will look for the output files directly into the output folder mentioned?? If not view in browser?

Comment: It's hard to say, because most options like build, rebuild, publish can change search path or output path by editing .pubxml and .xxproj file. And after that, then can work well. But for this special option, no valid way to control it dynamically. (Maybe it can be controled by changing a config file in someplace in C root, but the point is no document provided introduce this). As i know, so far i only find this option has this behaviour.